# Equivalent query of "Select All"

Tags: 7, database

I have this query:

```
SELECT * pg_type;
```

What is its equivalent query in Drupal 7?

My code throws an error.

```
$query = db_select('pg_type', 't1', array('target' => 'import'));       
$result = $query->execute();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * pg_type
```

isn't a valid SQL query; presumably you meant:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_type;
```

which in Drupal-ese is:

```
$query = db_select('pg_type', 't')->fields('t');
```

Output of the above:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM {pg_type} t
```